# Un-escaping characters when using jQuery.post()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm making a site where users can submit some code which is then received by a php script and stored in a file on the server. I am using the jQuery $.post() method to send the code to the php script. The problem I have is that when I do this jQuery escapes any single quotes, double quotes or backslashes with a backslash. This means when the code is then retrieved from the file it contains unwanted backslashes and wont execute properly. How can I un-escape these characters whilst making sure i don't effect anything in case the users code contains a wanted escaped character. Example below:

Users code:

```
var someText = 'Don\'t';
```

jQuery that submits this:

```
$.post("/submit.php", {id: 123, code: {main: "var someText = 'Don\'t';", foo: "bar"}}).done(function(data) {
    if (data === 'success') {
        // Do something.
    }
}
```

PHP script that saves it to file:

```
foreach($_POST['code'] as $file => $content) {
    if (ctype_alnum($file)) {
        file_put_contents("/code/" . $_POST['id'] . "/" . $file, $content);
    }
}
```

Resultant file that gets stored on the server:

```
var someText = \'Don\\\'t\';
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this turned out to be much simpler than I anticipated and I realized this as soon as I posted but I'll leave the question here for future reference.

All I needed to do was to modify the PHP script to use the [stripcslashes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripcslashes.php) method to remove the unwanted escape characters at the server's end. Modified PHP code below:

```
foreach($_POST['code'] as $file => $content) {
    if (ctype_alnum($file)) {
        file_put_contents("/code/" . $_POST['id'] . "/" . $file, stripcslashes($content));
    }
}
```